# Im trying to send a simple predefined command to a background console. (Win10)

Tags: background-process

Ok, so i had been trying ways to do this, but i see myself getting stuck over and over again. What i'm trying to accomplish is that i can create a script that will send a predefined command (shutdown) to my background process. As of now i have had no luck. The program itself is a console. I used a script to make it a background shell. The only way i'm able to shut it down now would be to simply shut it down trough the task manager. The process name is "unturned.exe" (yes, if any of you know, its an unturned server) but since i am fairly new to programming myself, and the server being for my little brother, i am simply out of ideas. Since i have found help here before i thought i'd ask one of you guys.

Comment: I am not familiar with unturned and what protocol it speaks,so it is hard to answer the question how to send a command. However if you do not have a client command which can communicate with the server and if there is no easy protocol to speak, then killing the task is not a bad option.`taskkill /F /FI "IMAGENAME EQ unturned.exe"`

Comment: The unturned server window is basicly an actual windows command promt. So if that helps.. Also, the shutdown command saves progress and shuts it down at the exact same time. If it wont save 45 minutes of progress would be gone.

Comment: It is a pity that the server is not crash safe. I think there is a way to remote enter commands on consoles, not sure if this works for hidden commands, sorry. Hopefully this comments help somebody else to know whats needed.